# Saving Array of custom class locally on device

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I have a Custom Class that works as a model for an array. The elements of they array are got from an API using *Alamofire*.
The user of the app can save some elements of the array from a tableview to display even when they don't have internet. I'm trying to using User Defaults however getting error.

**Custom Class for Array**

```
class LatestNews {

    private var _id : Int!
    private var _link : Int!
    private var _category : String!
    private var _tag : String!
    private var _headline : String!
    private var _story : String!

    var latestNews : LatestNews!
    var latest = [LatestNews]()

    var id : Int {
        if _id == nil {
            _id = 0
        }
        return _id
    }

    var link : Int {
        if _link == nil {
            _link = 0
        }
        return _link
    }

    var category : String {
        if _category == nil {
            _category = ""
        }
        return _category
    }

    var tag : String {
        if _tag == nil {
            _tag = ""
        }
        return _tag
    }

    var headline : String {
        if _headline == nil {
            _headline = ""
        }
        return _headline
    }

    var story : String {
        if _story == nil {
            _story = ""
        }
        return _story

    init(getLatest : [String: Any]) {

        if let id = getLatest["id"] as? Int {
            self._id = id
        }

        if let link = getLatest["link"] as? Int {
            self._link = link
        }

        if let category = getLatest["category"] as? String {
            self._category = category
        }

        if let tag = getLatest["tag"] as? String {
            self._tag = tag
        }

        if let headline = getLatest["headline"] as? String {
            self._headline = headline
        }

        if let story = getLatest["story"] as? String {
            self._story = story
        }
    }

}
```

**UserDefaults Function**

```
func transferOfflineData(news: [LatestNews]) {
        self.offlineData = news

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "OfflineData") == nil {
            let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.offlineData)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "OfflineData")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } else {
            self.prevOfflineData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "OfflineData") as! [LatestNews]
            self.prevOfflineData.append(offlineData.first!)
            let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.prevOfflineData)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "OfflineData")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
```

**Error i get**

```
2018-01-04 00:26:54.967563+0530 Khabar7[74210:3333998] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7f7f0ee0c0b0 of class 'Khabar7.LatestNews' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Khabar7.LatestNews replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
2018-01-04 00:26:54.970076+0530 Khabar7[74210:3333998] Unrecognized selector -[Khabar7.LatestNews replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

Please advise me if there is a better way to go about this or something I'm doing wrong and I can improve in my code.

Comment: User defaults should only be used to store simple values (like settings). Storing large amount / complicated data in user defaults is not a good practice. I would recommend looking into Core Data

Comment: >90 SO search results for "does not implement methodSignatureForSelector trouble ahead" – and none of them gave a hint where the problem is?

Comment: @MartinR No relevant response was found

Comment: @Malik How do i use core data for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To use `NSKeyedArchiver` your class must inherit from `NSObject` and must adopt `NSCoding`. Since all properties are property list compliant I'd prefer `JSONSerialization` or `PropertyListSerialization`.

If you are using Swift 4 the `Codable` protocol provides a very convenient way to serialize classes and structs without the requirement to inherit from `NSObject`.

---

Side note:

Private backing variables to get read-only variables (aka constants) are ridiculous in Swift. Declare constants as `let` and forget the objective-c-ish instance variables with a leading underscore.

The Swift way of your class is

```
class LatestNews {

    let id: Int
    let link: Int
    let category: String
    let tag: String
    let headline: String
    let story: String

    var latestNews: LatestNews!
    var latest = [LatestNews]()

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int ?? 0
        link = dictionary["link"] as? Int ?? 0
        category = dictionary["category"] as? String ?? ""
        tag = dictionary["tag"] as? String ?? ""
        headline = dictionary["headline"]  as? String ?? ""
        story = dictionary["story"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Will take care of the side note from next time but can you recommend me into a direction Im very new to this language. I am using Swift 4

Comment: Please read [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) and watch the WWDC 2017 video [What is new in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/)